# Qt dataChanged signal - not using provided cell range

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm hoping somebody can provide some assistance with an issue I'm observing with the dataChanged signal. After emit'ing this signal with a restricted cell range, the data model appears to call data(...) on every single visible cell.

For example:

```
QModelIndex bl = index(1, 1);
QModelIndex tr = index(1, 5);
emit dataChanged(bl, tr);
```

If 5 rows and 5 columns are visible, this signal will trigger 25 calls to data(), as opposed to the expected 5.

Reading the Qt documentation, I understand there is no guarantee to only call 5 times, but I'm curious if there's an accepted way of most of the time minimizing the range.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitations on number of `data()` calls. It totally depends on the view's implementation. For example, sometimes I notice that the view calls the model's `data()` when the view gains focus, without any `dataChanged` signals, without any other interaction at all. So, you should be ready to handle it. If you want to control `data()` calls count, the only way is to implement your own view.

Answer (score 0):

data() is called to get data stored under different Qt::ItemDataRole (like Qt::DecorationRole and Qt::DisplayRole).
data() will be called several time for a same item. So, it's normal that you have more calls than modified items.

Comment: should have included this in my description, but i have model decoration turned off. I only receive data() for DisplayRole.